# How to extends classes with JHipster entity generator?

Tags: java, jhipster

I'm new to Jhipster and I'm trying to understand how Jhipster entity generator work.

I'm trying create 3 simple class: Person, Professor, Student. I created a first entity (Person) and then I would like to create a second one (Professor) and make it extend to the first one but it's not proposed.

How to make the "professor" extends to "Person"? Am I suppose to do it directly on the code or did I miss something somewhere?

Comment: Were you able to solve this or did you find any turnaround?

Comment: Maybe there is solution nowaday with Jhipster. But a year ago in order to keep Jhipster in my project and after a lot of reading I choosed to make either one to one relationships between Person and Professor or to "duplicate" the same properties in the Professor and the Student depending of the situation

Answer (score 1):

As per the docs https://www.jhipster.tech/jhipster-uml/ inheritance is **not** yet possible by jhipster entity generator yet.

But you can do it manually once entity generator generates the entities.

See this too.

https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-uml/issues/96

Answer (score 0):

jhipster generates entities not only as classes (spring beans), but also for everything else in the "jhipster-construct": Spring security, relationships, database layout incl. liquibase database refactoring, services, repositories, DTOs, the frontend components with Angular or React, validation and integration and performance tests for back- and frontend. And all in a "best-practice"-manner, with i18n related stuff etc., including two stages, a development and a production profile (with a database for each stage). Additionally, jhipster provides you with all the configuration to deploy contionuously to e.g. heroku with jenkins controlling your git pushes.

To build abstract (java) classes or (java) interfaces isn't possible this way. That may make sense in some business logic, which is to be implemented after generation or there may be other ways than inheritance (e.g. see [services](https://www.jhipster.tech/creating-a-spring-service/) and [dtos](https://www.jhipster.tech/using-dtos/)).
The jhipster-generated construct for backend and frontend - or even for microservices and gateways - shows the paths to stay on.

You can manage a lot of things that persons and professors share with OneToOne- or OneToMany-relationships between them and/or additional entities by thinking of database normalization - at least, I have done it this way :-)